# DateTime.Parse not recognising UK formats anymore

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have code that used to work, but has now moved to a new server and has stopped working as 27-11-2013 is not being recognised as a valid datetime.  It *used* to so I don't want to make any code changes as there's obviously a server config change that needs to happen.  But which region/locale setting affects DateTime.Parse?  I've tried changing quite a number of them but not one has worked yet.

Oh, and I don't want to/can't use ParseExact...

Comment: `DateTime.Parse` uses the current culture if you don't specify a different.

Comment: You might have to change the regional settings of the user that is set up to run the application pools. ParseExact and/or specifying culture is usually more robust in server side solution.

Comment: If you don't want to make any code changes, why not post this in [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/?as=1)? For Windows 7, this page details how to change the [system locale](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/change-the-system-locale)

Comment: Oo, regional settings for a user, that sounds like it might make sense.

Answer (score 3):

[`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses the current culture if you don't specify a different.

```
DateTime dt= DateTime.Parse("27-11-2013", new CultureInfo("en-gb"));
```

Comment: I said in the question I didn't want to make any code changes - as this did work.  Where does the culture need changing at a server level in order to achieve this?

Comment: @Paul why don't you want to make code changes? Clearly, your code is error prone.

Comment: @Paul: have a look: [MSDN: How to: Set the Culture and UI Culture for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.ASPX)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
CultureInfo customCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Parse("27-11-2013", customCulture.DateTimeFormat);
```

Comment: Arrggg Tim 13seconds before me ^^

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in web.config like below

```
    <globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB"/>
```